# Should I use a single object or individual values as attributes in an Angular directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, attributes

This is kind of a 'best practices' question, but I still think there may be a correct answer.

I have a directive with six configurable options. Should I set up six different attributes on the directive (like below):

```
<my-directive
  my-width="300"
  my-height="300"
  my-status="true"
  my-foo="yes"
  my-bar="no">
</my-directive>
```

or, should I pass a configuration object into a single attribute (like below):

```
<my-directive my-options="options"></my-directive>
```

Is this just preference or is there a generally preferred method? Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: I usually prefer the six attributes. Directives attributes that modify the view should stay in the HTML and not in the JS. I mean theses attribute may have to be change by an integrator and they shouldn't like to go deep in the code to find it. But that's just one opinion.

Comment: Third case is using combination of both. Is easiest to write javascript objects for js developers, but also easy for others to override by attribute if you are parsing attributes inside the directive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a *mostly* matter of preference. Since you can achieve the eventual outcome with both routes. I personally prefer to see individual attributes as suggested in your first example for the sake of working with verbose, expressive elements.

Just by looking at `<my-directive my-width="300" my-height....>` in your first example, I can make an educated guess as to what this directive is used for and can easily piece together what is going on. Just seeing `my-options="options"`, I would have no idea unless I dug through some code to understand the intention of this element.

As a single developer on a project, though, this may be a low-priority consideration - often chalked up as "well, whats the difference?", but as you introduce other members working on the same code base, having verbosity can alleviate struggles to understand your intentions, especially to developers who are not as familiar with AngularJS.

As far as technical benefits, say for example you wish to only apply a style rule to elements whose attributes include `my-foo`. This becomes trivial with css selectors with the following

```
[my-foo="yes"] {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}

[my-foo="no"] {
    background-color: tomato;
}
```

Another quick example - say you have jQuery in your project and wish to do something like

```
$("[my-bar='no']") // do whatever
```

Doing these tasks the other route has the potential to be tricky. Consider this real-word example: A UX designer wants to leverage these manipulations, but is say, not very savvy with AngularJS - these tasks become unnecessarily painful.

When you begin to consider aspects and examples such as these, having **granular** control on your elements becomes invaluable. To your original interest in asking this question, surely everyone can understand the desire for consolidating this into something succinct like `my-options="options"` - but striving for shorter code is not always advantageous.

All considered, a combination of both is likely ideal depending on the *perceived importance* of the attribute you are working with. `height`, `width`, `status`? - likely important and descriptive enough to standalone. A complex statistical object with many fields used in directive processing? - likely qualifies to remain an object.

Comment: This is correct. I just would like to throw in that it could become a problem in a rare case where you have multiple directives with the same attribute names on one element.